# Best way to put images and css circles in a list

Tags: html, css

I need to create an unordered list as menu for a small project. There are 3 categories and 9 workshops. For every workshop I want to put a little image on the left and a **css** circle on the right.

I really want to do it as correctly as possible but I am a beginner so I am not sure about the best practices.

Here is my code :

```css
ul#menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 285px;
  padding-left: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul#menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
ul#menu > li > span {
  display: block;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #4D4D4D;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center
}
ul#menu > li:first-child {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  color: #050505;
}
ul#menu ul li {
  height: 35px;
  padding-left: 0;
  background-color: #007CB7;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
ul#menu ul li:hover {
  background-color: #8BBDD9;
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <span>Category 1</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Workshop 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Category 2</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Workshop 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Category 3</span>
    <ul>
      <li>Workshop 3</li>
      <li>Workshop 4</li>
      <li>Workshop 5</li>
      <li>Workshop 6</li>
      <li>Workshop 7</li>
      <li>Workshop 8</li>
      <li>Workshop 9</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is that the best way for this ? On my code, it misses the image and the circle. Can you please give me some tips / advices to do it ?

I attache a screenshot of the result I want to reach.[My menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9Hq1.png)

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, add your desired styling to css. Also, most people think, that direct id targeting is better(`ul#menu` -> `#menu`)

```css
#menu {
display: inline-block;
width: 285px;
padding-left: 0;
border: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}

#menu ul {
padding-left: 0;
}

ul#menu > li > span {
display: block;
height: 35px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
background-color: #4D4D4D;
color: #FAFAFA;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center
}

#menu > li:first-child {
height: 50px;
background-color: #E0E0E0;
color: #050505;
}

ul#menu ul li {
height: 35px;
padding-left: 0;
background-color: #007CB7;
color:#FAFAFA;
font-size: 14px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

#menu ul li:hover {
background-color: #8BBDD9;
color: #050505;
font-weight:bold;
list-style-type: none;
}

/* ADDED */
#menu ul li:before{
  content:"";
  width:1em;
  height:1em;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-right:0.5em;
  background: /* your image*/ red;
  display:inline-block;
}
#menu ul li:after{
  content:"•";
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
                <li>
                    <span>Category 1</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Workshop 1</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Category 2</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Workshop 2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span>Category 3</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Workshop 3</li>
                        <li>Workshop 4</li>
                        <li>Workshop 5</li>
                        <li>Workshop 6</li>
                        <li>Workshop 7</li>
                        <li>Workshop 8</li>
                        <li>Workshop 9</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Many thanks. That solution works very well but my circles change color (red, green or orange) and the image is different for every workshop.  ... that solution would be perfect if it would be every time the same circle and the same image. Is it possible to do it that way and change the colors and the image automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

Like Pepo_rasta has written: You can use Pseudo-elements.

For getting a circle you can use border-radius. Give it a value of 50%.

Example:

```
ul#menu li li:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Adding the image should be possible with background-image.

```
  background-position: right;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);
  background-size: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Comment: Looking at @Pepo_rasta answer, that border-radius would be on the ::after element. The ::before is being used for the background image.

Comment: Many thanks. That solution works very well but my circles change color. 1 time it is red, 1 time it is green, ... that solution would be perfect if it would be every time the same circle. Is it possible to do it that way and change the colors automatically ?

Comment: That's strange! You set the color by using "background-color: whatever". Why should it change?

Comment: In fact the color is set by the difficulty of the workshop. As you can see on my screenshot, it depends of the workshops. With this solution (which is a good solution) I can fix only 1 color for every workshops and this is not exactly what I want to do.

Comment: Perhaps you can adjust my idea here to your project? http://codepen.io/mizech/pen/PNpgrE Please read my comments for explanations.

Comment: Many thanks for your link, I will check it :) have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

You also could use a table.
If you replace the background-color with your background images it should look like your screenshot.

```css
th{
  background-color: grey;
}

td{
  background-color: yellow;
}

#circle{
  background-color: green;
  width : 25px;
}

#pic{
  width:25px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
  <th colspan="3">
    category 1
  </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="pic"></td>
    <td>workshop1</td> 
    <td id="circle"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">
    category 2
  </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="pic"></td>
    <td>workshop2</td> 
    <td id="circle"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">
    category 2
  </th>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="pic"></td>
    <td>workshop3</td> 
    <td id="circle"></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td id="pic"></td>
    <td>workshop4</td> 
    <td id="circle"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </body>

</html>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NYrgpqK9t0wunr8ktweL?p=preview)